# Why php versions 5.4.45 on server still can run code with "eregi" function?

Tags: php, warnings, php-5.4

why this function "eregi" its on server still running don't have error.

but when I download this source code and gonna edit. its warning This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0 , but I see this server use php 5.4.45

and I use php version 5.4.25 but cant run and need to change "preg_match()"

and code on server can run with no quote in [ ], but on my server need **quote** in [''] for running code I'm so confuse. TT

source code in server can use $_SESSION[newsession]  no double or single quote in brackets' ,but this code on my desktop it's error need to add '', "" in brackets' ,
in server php 5.4.45 , my desktop php 5.4.25

Comment: You should upgrade PHP on both environments immediately. PHP 5.3 and 5.4 haven't been supported or gotten a single security update for the last **_7-8 years_**.

Comment: The function `eregi()` was _deprecated_ in PHP 5.3, but it wasn't _removed_ until PHP 7. So you can still use that function in all 5.x versions. If you see the deprecation warning locally but not on the server, it most likely have to do with what error reporting level PHP is set to. It's not uncommon that servers are set to E_ERROR (not logging notices/warnings) or similar, while dev-environments often are set to E_ALL (logging everything, including warnings/notices).

Comment: _"and code on server can run with no quote in [ ], but on my server need quote in [''] for running code"_ - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73771965/edit) the question and include some examples of what you mean. It's super unclear atm.

Comment: @M. Eriksson source code in server can use $_SESSION[newsession] no double or single quote in brackets' ,but this code on my desktop it's error need to add '', "" in brackets' , in server php 5.4.45 , my desktop php 5.4.25

Comment: It's the same thing. Your local server can also do that. However, you will get _"Notice: Use of undefined constant newsession - assumed 'newsession'"_ because your local PHP configuration shows those warnings, while the server hides them. Try and set the servers error_reporting to E_ALL (but make sure "display_errors" are off). Then you visit the site and check the web servers error log. You should then see the same warnings/notices you see on your local machine. The server has the same issues, the warnings/notices are just hidden.